# Debugging an RNN

Tags: debugging, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I'm currently writing my own RNN from scratch, using pretty much only numpy. I'm basically stuck because I checked all the gradients from each individual layer and I have all the unit tests here: https://github.com/OneRaynyDay/BibleNet/blob/master/Unit%20tests.ipynb
https://github.com/OneRaynyDay/BibleNet/blob/master/Gradient%20Solver%20Unit%20Test.ipynb

However, when I do backpropagation on my net with relatively reasonable weights initialization and unit-tested gradient optimizers(), I can see that the graph is DEFINITELY not what I want. I passed in a relatively simple corpus, which is basically this article from here: http://www.dailycal.org/2016/10/18/students-gather-hear-faculty-speak-trump-teach/  which is less than 1000 words, it should be overfitting very easily. However, the cost function looks something like this:
[image]
This is definitely not something that's converging. It's jumping up and down like it's not actually learning anything. What should I do in terms of debugging?

I cannot provide an MVCE for this example simply because it's a functional test error, which integrates all parts of the library that I made. Therefore, an MVCE is the entire project. Feel free to clone it from github though.

## Suspicious places

I feel like the error is occuring because of my neural network architecture. **Maybe the way I'm handling the continued iterations is not correct**. Here is the zoomed in code:

```
        # Save typing 
        c = lambda arg: self.constants[arg]
        p = lambda arg: self.params[arg]

        # Step 1: Word embedding forward:
        words_chosen = word_embedding_forward(p("words"), x)

        # Step 2: rnn forward:
        h = rnn_forward(words_chosen, p("W_xh"), p("W_hh"), p("b_rnn"), h0)

        # Step 3: affine forward:
        affine = rnn_affine_forward(h, p("W_hy"), p("b_affine"))

        # step 4: softmax forward and backward:
        loss, dout = rnn_softmax(affine, y) 

        # step 3: affine backward:
        dh, dW_hy, db_affine = rnn_affine_backward(h, p("W_hy"), p("b_affine"), dout)

        # step 2: rnn backward:
        dW_hh, dW_xh, dx, db_rnn, dh0 = rnn_backward(words_chosen, p("W_xh"), p("W_hh"), p("b_rnn"), h0, h, dh)

        # step 1: Word embedding backward:
        dwords = word_embedding_backward(dx, p("words"), x)

        # Returns the loss and all the derivatives along with the fields.
        return (loss, [[p("words"), dwords], 
               [p("W_xh"), dW_xh], 
               [p("W_hh"), dW_hh],
               [p("W_hy"), dW_hy],
               [p("b_affine"), db_affine],
               [p("b_rnn"), db_rnn],
               [h0, dh0]], h[:,-1,:])
```

**Another suspicion is that I'm not handling the hidden states correctly**. I'm taking a hidden state from the previous sample and hooking that hidden layer state straight into the next sample.

Here's an illustration:
`[a,b,c,d,e,f,g] is the sequence`

`input (a,b,c) -> (b,c,d) output (uses zeros as initial hidden layer)`

`We skip over to d: input (d,e,f) -> (e,f,g) output (uses previous hidden state of c)`

Comment: Have you checked your gradient norms over time? With Vanilla RNN you easily get into exploding/vanishing gradients.

Comment: Hi - no I haven't but the issue is this happens even with a time-sequence size of 2, where the exploding/vanishing gradient isn't as apparent. (In fact, the graph here is of time step size 2)